# Export hidden fields to CSV with Views Bulk Operations (VBO) module

Tags: 8, importing-exporting, views

I use [Views Bulk Operations (VBO)](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module and [VBO export](https://www.drupal.org/project/vbo_export) module. I have a Table display with a couple of fields. Is there a solution to export also fields which are `Exclude from display` (hidden)?

So they will be exported, but not visible in the view?

Comment: Instead of exclude from display, you could add a class to those fields and just hide them with CSS.

Comment: IIRC this was possible in D7 but it's not the same in D8. Even if you split it in 2 Displays, one for the table and the other for CSV (for example Attachment Display) you will get two tables, because the one relating to the export controls which Views results end up in the CSV and needs to be visible. You could possibly create a custom module that would hide the Attachment table (twig template) and use the Page table selection with Export to CSV option in Attachment.

Comment: Did you consider using views_data_export instead? It is not an action but a different display that can have completely different fields but it can be attached to another display to show up there and respects its filters, so you can configure your filters there and then click on the CSV icon for the download. There is also an issue in the queue to re-add the support for batch export for large data sets. Note that 8.5 needs a patch too currently to add the _format query argument.

Comment: @Berdir Yes I tried also . But the problem is with `views_data_export` I can't make a part selection? In my case I need the possibility they can make a partial selection of certain rows and then export them. Or is there a way to make this possible with `views_data_export` module?

Comment: I don't think so, your only option is to use exposed filters.